# How to pass parameter to a txt Resource in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net

I created a resource in Asp.net name Email.txt.
there is a parameter in my file that i must pass that parameter to txt file.
this is my code that i call my resource :

```
 mailBody  = My.Resources.Email
```

but I dont know How can i pass my parameter to txt file:
this is a piece of my txt file content :

```
<p>Hello</p><label style='font-weight:bold'>**{0}**</label>
```

How can I send a parameter to txt file that replace instead of {0}.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Assuming mailBody is a string with the text of the body of the email, you could just do

```
mailBody.Replace("{0}", "your replacement value here");
```

Of course, if you have multiple values to replace, you can create a loop to loop through each n value for {n}.

Answer (score 0):

```
String.Format(mailBody,parameter);
```